# Stop Sqlite3 merge conflicts and always use production version?

Tags: git, github

I'm having major problems with git merge conflicts between my production vpm and my local machine, mainly with sqlite3.

I fix any bugs / add new features on my local machine and then

`git add .`

`git commit -m "message"`

`git push -u origin development`

Then merge the master and development branch on GH.

My production vpm always has an updated version of the sqlite3 database (obviously as users are registering etc) which I don't have on my local machine.

Every time I `git pull` to my production machine, I get a merge conflict with the `sqlite3` db.

I've accidentally overidden the production database with the one from my local machine and wiped accounts and then had to git reset.

It's unclear to me whether I should make a .gitignore, I ran `git rm db.sqlite` but then it was removed from my local machine totally which I obviously don't want.

I basically want the production machine to always be the database that is used regardless of any changes to the database locally when I `git pull`.

Comment: Your SQLite database probably shouldn't be tracked at all. Data generally doesn't belong in your code repository. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/1274057/354577.

Comment: How can I stop it from being tracked? I've ran `git rm --cached db.sqlite3` then `git pull` but ended up still having problems with `error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge: sqlite3`

Comment: Right, so back the file up, pull, then replace it. (Assuming you plant to continue using a file-based database I also strongly recommend adding its name to your `.gitignore`.)

Comment: Cheers, I've added to `.gitignore` and `git rm --cached db.sqlite3` so shouldn't have any more merge problems with it going forward. If you add your comment as an answer I'll mark it as correct.